# Google Analytics API Filter By ga:campaign

Tags: php, google-analytics

I need to filter results by ga:medium & ga:campaign.

I can bring data with ga:medium filter but not with ga:campaign.

Sample Code:

```
$query->setStartDate(new \DateTime('-1week'));
$query->setEndDate(new \DateTime());
$query->setMetrics(array('ga:bounces'));
$query->setDimensions(array('ga:day', 'ga:medium', 'ga:campaign'));
$query->setFilters(['ga:medium=='.$medium, 'ga:campaign=='.$campaign]);
```

Edit:

When i use "segments", i'm getting some data but i'm not really sure what.

```
$query->setSegment('sessions::condition::ga:campaign=='.$campaign);
```

Question 2: If i want to get the data of "clicks" for that exact medium and campaign, should i use bounce or something else?

Comment: $query->setFilters(['ga:medium=='.$medium, 'ga:campaign=='.$campaign]); what library do you use?

Comment: https://github.com/widop/google-analytics